# Defining project name inside docker-compose configuration

Tags: docker-compose

Can you actually define the project name inside the compose configuration file itself, rather than as an environment variable or command-line flag?
I suspect it may avoid some trouble in some scenarios.

I guess overriding that name might still be possible by env or flag.

Answer (score 5):

Not yet (as of version 1.6.2), however, it is being discussed https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/745

Comment: Thanks. Frankly it is also a pain that there isn't a notion of default parameters in the docker-compose yml (or is there?). I.e. you either use an env var, or hard-code values. This is too stiff IMO, e.g. if one wishes to override a port on a certain deploy environment. Is there any programming language api to augment use of the yml definition?